# Passing an array or list of strings from one action to another when redirecting

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a post action Import:

```
public ActionResult Import()
{
    var fileNames = new List<String>();

    foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath))
    {
        //do a whole bunch of stuff
        ...
        fileNames.Add(path.Split('\\').Last());            
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { InvalidFiles = fileNames });
}
```

As you can see, it redirects to an `Index` action, passing the `List<String>` of file names

```
public ActionResult Index(List<String> InvalidFiles)
{
    return View();
}
```

In the `Index` action, the List comes in with the right amount of elements, however all the actual strings has been changed from the filename to the string "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]".

Any idea why this is happening?  Is there a better way to pass the list to the new action, possibly using TempData?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata.aspx) to temporally hold the data between actions.

```
public ActionResult Import()
{
    var fileNames = new List<String>();

    foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath))
    {
        //do a whole bunch of stuff
        ...
        fileNames.Add(path.Split('\\').Last());            
    }

    TempData["fileNames"] = fileNames;

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}


public ActionResult Index()
{
    var invalidFiles = TempData["fileNames"] as List<String>;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Yep, figured that.  Any idea why my original method produced such a weird result?

Comment: @link664 That is because MVC calls the `ToString()` method to produce the route values. Query string is a key-value pair list. Hence you can not send a `List<String>` using query string.