# Html.RenderAction not hitting default route as expected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a default route specified like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                                  // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                               // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", RouteName = "Default" },     // Parameter defaults
            new { controller = @"[^\.]*" }                              // Constraints (Ignore urls with periods in them)
        );
```

I have a controller called Test and an action on Test called DoSomething that is defined like this:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(int someId, int someotherId, IEnumerable<string> listOfSomething, bool flag, bool flag2)
```

I am trying to call the action like this:

```
        var parameters = new RouteValueDictionary();

        parameters.Add("someId", id);
        parameters.Add("someotherId", otherId);
        parameters.Add("flag", flag1);
        parameters.Add("flag2", flag2);
        for (int i = 0; i < thisList.Count; i++)
        {
            parameters.Add("listOfSomething[" + i + "]", thisList[i]);
        }
        Html.RenderAction("DoSomething", "Test", parameters);
```

The Html.RenderAction call is failing with the InvalidOperationException : No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

What would be causing this? The default route should pick this call up?

Answer (score 0):

*No route in the route table matches the supplied values* indicates that no valid route in `RouteCollection` matches the requested URL, i.e. your default route parameters count doesn't match with `DoSomething` action parameters (1 parameter : 5 parameters).

Also note that `IEnumerable<string>` considered as complex object, therefore you can't pass it as part of `RouteValueDictionary` parameters in URL. Hence, you should pass only 4 value parameters & pass `IEnumerable<string>` object as `Session` or `TempData` content.

First, define a custom route with 4 parameters as such on top of default one (avoid modifying default route which placed last in route order, it may required for other routes):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Custom", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{someId}/{someotherId}/{flag}/{flag2}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", someId = "", someotherId = "", flag = "", flag2 = "" }, // Parameter defaults
    new { controller = @"[^\.]*" } // Constraints (Ignore urls with periods in them)
);
```

Then, edit controller action method to receive 4 parameters (strip off `IEnumerable<string>` from parameters list, based from explanation above):

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult DoSomething(int someId, int someotherId, bool flag, bool flag2)
    {
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

And pass parameters for redirect thereafter, with `IEnumerable` object stored in `TempData` or `Session` variable:

```
var parameters = new RouteValueDictionary();

parameters.Add("someId", id);
parameters.Add("someotherId", otherId);
parameters.Add("flag", flag1);
parameters.Add("flag2", flag2);

var list = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < thisList.Count; i++)
{
    list.Add(thisList[i]);
}

TempData["listOfSomething"] = list;

Html.RenderAction("DoSomething", "Test", parameters);
```

Or define parameters directly in `RedirectToAction`:

```
var list = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < thisList.Count; i++)
{
    list.Add(thisList[i]);
}

TempData["listOfSomething"] = list;

Html.RenderAction("DoSomething", "Test", new { someId = id, someotherId = otherId, flag = flag1, flag2 = flag2 });
```

If `thisList` is already `IEnumerable<string>` instead, remove `for` loop & just assign it straight to `Session`/`TempData`:

```
TempData["listOfSomething"] = thislist;
```

The list of parameters can be retrieved using this way:

```
var listOfParameters = TempData["listOfSomething"] as List<string>;
```

Similar issues as reference:

[How to pass List in Redirecttoaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108770/how-to-pass-list-in-redirecttoaction)

[Sending a list using RedirectToAction in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684389/sending-a-list-using-redirecttoaction-in-mvc4)

[Passing an array or list of strings from one action to another when redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073757/passing-an-array-or-list-of-strings-from-one-action-to-another-when-redirecting)

[Routing with Multiple Parameters using ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc)

[How to pass multiple objects using RedirectToAction() in Asp.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744054/how-to-pass-multiple-objects-using-redirecttoaction-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: OP's code for passing `IEnumerable<string>` as route values is perfectly fine (although it risks exceeding the query string limit if the collection is large)